# icCube cascading Filters with multiple selections

Tags: filtering, iccube, iccube-reporting

Looking at this, 
http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=I%20want%20a%20BigMac

I want to do the same thing but with a multi-selection (Buttons) first filter
which would reduce the choices list on a second filter (TreeFilter)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that report's case if the first filter is a multi-select one, you have to add this mdx in the second's Query Wizard: `Descendants(@{category})`.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to return just the first level children, you have to add a parameter for the level, like this: `Descendants(@{category}, 1)`. Without the second parameter near the children it returns also the parent. Also you can check [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Descendants.php) how this function works.

Comment: Dear Istvan, I just tried your suggestion... It gives me the same list in the second filter as in the first one... Not the descendants of the first selection...

Comment: Ok Istvan, I understand... This is now working... Thanks a lot!  Is there a way to go further ?  I mean Filter on the first selection and bring the members of another dimension ?